# Has there ever been a thorough search of Loch Ness (for the Loch Ness Monster)

Tags: cryptozoology, loch-ness-monster

The burden of proof is on the people who believe they have sighted the Loch Ness Monster to prove it exists with verifiable evidence, however it would be possible to remove all doubt by thoroughly searching Loch Ness. Has this ever been suggest, attempted or completed?

Comment: AFAIK it has been completely sonar scanned at least once.

Comment: According to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness the Loch has a surface area of 56.4 km2 (21.8 sq mi) and an average depth of 132 m (433 ft). That's a crazy amount of (murky) water to "search thoroughly", even for a relatively large creature. Its hard to imagine that a search could be sufficiently comprehensive to satisfy people that *nothing* could have been missed.

Comment: @BradC: How hard it is to search it is unrelated to if people are satisfied by the search. It could be 100x100m large and people would still believe.

Comment: The Loch Ness Monster is anti-quantum: it only exists when not being observed:)

Answer (score 6):

A simple Wikipedia search lists some of the more extensive searches:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loch_Ness_Monster#Searches_for_the_monster

Some seem rather extensive, involving sonar surveys of the entire loch, submarine expeditions, microphones, etc.  The lack of data/evidence is deafening.